# Pandas GroupBy STDEV returns NaN, even after applying fillna()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

I have a DataFrame, from which I am creating a new calculated column. I then use `df.fillna(0.0)` to make sure I have no NaN values.

```
df = pd.read_csv("my_data.csv")
df['units_per_month'] = df['units'] / df['months_since_first_order']
df = df.fillna(0.0)
```

I then group by DataFrame by category `df_grp = df.groupby(['segments'])` and attempt to calculate the standard deviation `std_units_month = df_grp['units_per_month'].std()`

This works perfectly fine for 8 of my 11 categories, but for 3 of them, the std is returned as `NaN`

I know that I have all valid values and that all `NaN` values were filled because `df[['segments','units_per_month']][df['units_per_month'].isnull()]` returns an empty DataFrame.

I've also downloaded all the data and confirmed that nothing is awry.. excel can calculate all the stdevs..

Any thoughts on where I could have gone wrong?

Comment: What's the output of `df_grp['units_per_month'].count()` for the groups that return `NaN`? I'm guessing it's one?

Comment: appears they all return normally..

Comment: Kevin, you will want to explain what you mean by "normally". It will probably be help a lot to figure out what's going on if you tell us exactly what is `df_grp['units_per_month']` for the 3 categories in question.

Comment: thanks for the feedback Robert - I get my expected group counts ranging from 59 all the way up to 4280. The three groups that are returning nan are 2916, 4280, and 1192.

For clarity, the other values are 59, 312, 353, 436, 1421, 101, and 173. so my nans are definitely in my bigger groups

Comment: thanks for the help you guys, the answer was infinite values (facepalm)

Comment: @Kevin Hansen can you elaborate? What scenario would cause infinite values and what's the workaround. Just ran into the same problem.